How to secure double doors from a dog
TL;DR: How do I prevent double doors from being easily forced open by a strong push (aka a dog)?
Our basement has double doors that partition a guest bedroom/laundry area from the storage area/dog bedroom. The trouble is that the resident of the latter (the dog) likes to visit the residents of the former (the guests) and help herself to a few socks while she's there.
These doors were just decorative when we moved in, such that nothing other than two weak ball catches at the top were preventing this -- which is to say, nothing. So I pulled out the hole saw bits and installed a privacy lock, foolishly thinking the latch-and-strike-plate would secure the door when closed (regardless of whether locked) since that's how it works with single doors where the strike plate is in the frame.
In our first test run, the dog barreled through with zero difficulty. I foreseeably could have seen this coming. Unfortunately, reversing the door such that it pulls open into the dog region instead would be extremely awkward given the space on the dog's side of the border (and generally beyond my capabilities).
How do I best solve this otherwise without making it difficult for my parents to easily come in and out of the guest side? (Tempting as that is at times...and the dog is arguably stronger than they are at full velocity.) My best idea thus far is to install a floor lock on the side with the strike plate, such that a human can come in and out of the side with the lever. I don't love this since it's a bit of a fire hazard and so forth. Ideally, the doors would be better secured when the latch is in the strike plate, though I realize this might involve a much more complex operation with an orthogonal rod attached to the lock mechanism or something. Thanks!




As long as the door with the handle can always be opened by a human, there should be no issue with adding some way of locking the other door to the floor. Consult your local fire safety officer if in any doubt. I am not a fire safety officer.

upvote for including a picture of the cutie

Yeah I think that's the path of least resistance. And you're welcome! What you see here is the most contrition she's capable of affecting.

How about using a Barrell bolt latch vertically at the bottom of the door and drilling a shallow hole in the floor.
Not the most elegant solution, but it is easy to instal. There are multiple sizes as well.
Most dogs learn quickly when they can or cannot get into things.

Great idea. Is there any reason this can't go at the top, since it's way easier to drill into the top of the frame than the concrete floor? Since it has a slot to rotate the little handle into, I could imagine it either sliding up and turning into that slot or having the bolt attached to the frame (I think there's room) and slide down.

Generally, the dog would apply more pressure on the bottom 1/2 of the door, so my thinking was there would be a greater resistance to the dogs actions at the bottom...but the top could work if I have mentally over estimated  the power of your dog.

It's a great point. One of her rare displays of intelligence is to reach up for more leverage, so we'll try the top and see how it goes. Thx!

So far so good, the bolt latch (at the top, for now) is holding. We haven't eaten laundry in weeks. Thx!

A 3-point latch will latch (and unlatch) top, bottom and side with one handle and motion.
Since the term is used for various different products that are not the same, an image. No endorsement implied.
 Image Source
The single handle or lock operates all three bolts. Long rods connect the top and bottom bolts to the central bolt and handle. There are various implementations - the example shown appears to mount the rods in the edge of the door; many are surface-mounted on the inside of the door.

Thank you! I may file this away for next time, but it's just what I was imagining.

Most of the exterior mount rod locks I've seen have a T-bar handle to operate the lever that actuates the rods, but I don't see why you couldn't adapt a standard handle like the existing one.  I would think any handle bar that fits the square hole in the latch mechanicm would work.
